# Does Gilbraltar affect the weather in its climatological/meteorological neighbourhood?

Tags: weather, meteorology

When I was in [Gilbraltar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibraltar) a few years ago, several locals of both Spain and Gibraltar commented on the fact that the peninsula has a weather system distinct from the areas around it, and that the peninsula had an effect on the weather patterns of the surrounding areas (i.e. Spain & north-west Africa).

[image: Gibraltar in twilight] (licensed under the "[licencia de Creative Commons (“attribution”)](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/2.5/es/)", source: http://www.consumer.es/web/es/medio_ambiente/fotografias/2006/07/14/153891.php)

[image] (licensed under the [Creative Commons non-commercial attribution, no derivatives](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/2.0/deed.es_AR) source: http://www.viajeros.com/fotos/gibraltar-puerta-de-europa/78590)

From the shape and size of Gibraltar the assertion by the locals seems plausible. Is there a meteorological phenomenon surrounding this mountain that affects the weather of Spain or North-west Africa?

Does this big 'ol rock, cast as a [Pillar of Hercules](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pillars_of_Hercules), change the weather around it? It's a big rock, no doubt. But is it ***that*** big?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microclimate

Comment: I'm not sure how this question could be answered "No", whether we were talking about a mountain, or just a tall tree. Both have their microclimates: They divert wind, are cooler in the shade &  affect where rain lands. Both can affect global weather: the chaos effect suggests it takes very little. This suggests to me the question isn't well-formed. What are you skeptical about?

Comment: @Oddthinking: I'd kindly refer you back the question for another read, as it asks not whether Gibraltar has a different (micro-)climate, but whether it has an effect on the surrounding area of the sort that can be considered a meteorological phenomenon (viz. predictable, therefore not a result of chaos).

Comment: @Oddthinking: Perhaps the title should be edited to reflect the actual question? :)

Comment: I was/am reading it as having two claims:  1) the island has a weather system distinct from the areas around it, 2) the island had an effect on the weather patterns of the surrounding areas.  The first I was calling a microclimate, after @vartec. Sounds like the second one is the key one you are interested in, and now you are clarifying it as "predictable" which seems fair.

Comment: btw. it's peninsula, not an island.

Comment: @Oddthinking: Yes, please ignore the first claim – thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only a partial answer, that will hopefully be helpful to someone else:

[Workshop on “Unresolved issues in Mediterranean Sea Level”](http://imedea.uib-csic.es/proyecto/sealevel/)
Palma de Mallorca, 30th May – 1st June 2011

[Session 3](http://imedea.uib-csic.es/proyecto/sealevel/session_3.pdf)

> Mass changes in the nearby Atlantic or winds around Gibraltar can
>   induce sea level changes in the whole basin.

This is not peer-reviewed, and it is about ocean currents, not atmospheric conditions, which I would have though would be closely related but, it says:

> Recent efforts have been devoted to couple ocean and atmospheric models. However, we
>   feel that there is still a lack of clear conclusions about the improvements lead by coupled
>   models in front of forced models.

There is a strong wind weather pattern around Gibraltar called [Viento de Levante](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viento_de_Levante), which was researched in 1952, but I can't see the actual paper :-(